# Simple way to get the position of a character into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this `array`:

```
var arr = ['char', 'char', '@char', 'char', '@char'];
```

Is it possible to get the position of all `char` with `@`?

I write this code: (here the source http://jsfiddle.net/bq84zy1f/)

```
$('textarea').keyup(
    function() {
        var valOfTextarea = $(this).val();
        var splitedVal = valOfTextarea.split(/\s/);

        var indexOfAt = splitedVal.indexOf('@');

        console.log(splitedVal[indexOfAt]);
    }
);
```

I retrieve the index of `@` only, and when I write something following the `@` (@blabla) the index returns `-1`. But I want to get the position of the value with @char for example and always want to get also, the index even if the taped text is like @blablaba.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`map` method](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to filter out the items containing a `@` and return the indexes:

```
var indexOfAt = $.map(splitedVal, function(o, i){
  return o.indexOf('@') != -1 ? i : null;
});
```

The result is an array with the index of each item containing an `@`. With the example data, the result would be `[ 2, 4 ]`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bq84zy1f/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['hello','@hell','hii','@newhii'];
var patt = /^\@/;
for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    if(arr[i].match(patt))
    {
        alert(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the pure javascript code that will retun the position of all the elements that starts with @
The alert will be 1 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code returns an array

```
var splitedVal = valOfTextarea.split(/\s/);
```

You then want to check if the elements in that array contain @, your code is trying to match @ to individual the elements in the array see [JavaScript Array indexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp)

You actually need to step through the array and check the individual elements themselves

```
$('textarea').keyup(
    function() {
        var valOfTextarea = $(this).val();
        var splitedVal = valOfTextarea.split(/\s/);

        var indexOfAt = [];
        for(i = 0; i < splitedVal.length; i++) {
            if(splitedVal[i].indexOf('@') != -1) {
              indexOfAt.push(i)
            }
        }

        console.log(splitedVal);
        console.log(indexOfAt);

        for(i = 0; i < indexOfAt.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            console.log('with @ =>' + splitedVal[indexOfAt[i]]);
        }
    }
);
```